# What $watch method in angularjs really returns and how it works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, watch

I have difficulty understanding the following codes even with the comments

```
// Store the initial cell value so we can reset to it if need be
var oldCellValue;
var dereg = scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
    oldCellValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
    dereg(); // only run this watch once, we don't want to overwrite our stored value when the input changes
});
```

How many time does function dereg got called in this case? Is this a recursion?

Comment: This is easy to find out, just place a breakpoint in your code.

Comment: Hello, recursion. Recursion, hello!

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with recursion. (That said, the implementation seems buggy and very unlikely to work ad expected.)

Comment: @ExpertSystem Indeed. after reading the docs I found that the dereg has nothing to do with watch method itself, it's actually a deregistration function returned by the watch method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've shown is in a nutshell

- storing reference to *(just added)* `$watch()` returned value *(see below `$rootScope.$watch` returned value)*
- once first time is that `$watch()` called, it calls that referenced `function` - which leads to **ubinding** of that `$watch()`

Read this nice article

#### [Unbinding $watch() Listeners In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-unbinding-watch-listeners-in-angularjs.htm)

a small extract from a summary:

> As you can see, we're storing the function reference returned by the `$watch()` statement; then, once the `$watch()` fires a few times, we invoke that stored method, unbinding the $watch() listener.

In that example, there is an **if** statement, which could help us to decide, when is the best time to remove that `$watch()` (e.g. after the first evaluation) ...

The more detailed defintion of the `scope.$watch()` could be found here:

- [$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

And as we can see from this extract:

#### `$watch(watchExpression, [listener], [objectEquality]);`

> ...
>    **Returns** a deregistration function for this listener.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and particularly the nice article!

Comment: Great if that helped. This is nice feature, and you can also check the **angular once** https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once, which is the extension profiting from that... some readonly properties could be evaluated just once... and watch could be removed

Comment: +1, For clarification: It stores a reference to a function that removes the newly added watcher, since that is what $watch returns.